# I would like to bind to the specific port, but the port is still random

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bind

I finally fixed the problem but i still didn't know why it worked.
I find htons() to replace htonl().
Here are the code.

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int fd;

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htonl(11211);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)(&addr), sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    listen(fd, 5);

    sleep(1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `htons` for the port, because it's not a `long`.

Comment: And clearly on your undisclosed platform the result of `htonl()` was zero.

Answer (score 4):

`sin_port` is a 16-bit value and you are assigning a 32-bit value to it.  So the low-order bits are chopped off, leaving your `sin_port` being 0.  Print it out and see.

You can fix it by using `htons()` instead of `htonl()`, as any tutorial would show.